# This rating option has been disabled by the Android Market team

Tags: android, google-play

I'm seeing this message

> This rating option has been disabled
>   by the Android Market team

next to the "All" rating option for my app.  This is showing up for my apps that need Internet access to serve up adMob ads.  I am not allowed to select the All option.  My app is suitable for little kids, and the ads don't show up on the main game screen.  Does anyone know of a way to get around this?

Comment: Official policy: http://market.android.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=188189 I don't see anything about ads on there, but maybe it falls under user generated content?  Regardless, I'm sure there isn't a legal way around it, other than removing the ads.

Comment: I wonder if it has anything to do with the app type. I'm running into the same problem. Maybe it's because I built a file handler? Of course, Google doesn't explain *why* the option has been disabled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure you don't have location enabled?

I have an app that just requires Internet, and I can select "all", but another app with internet + coarse location cannot be rated "all", with the same "error" message.

Comment: I think that's it.  I guess I'll have to disable location.  Thank you.

Comment: Just as added info, this is explained on this page http://market.android.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=188189 under the Location header

Answer (score 1):

Should a child not be able to know where they are?

Comment: I don't get it either, but, I only had location enabled for admob and flurry...so I guess I'll have to disable it now.  I guess flurry won't be able to give me as much detail on location and adMob won't be able to targets the ads as well...but I need that ALL rating since my app is for little kids.

Comment: Yeah, flurry will only be able to go down to country level.  Shame.

Optional Permission:
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
If your application has location permissions, analytics will track where your application is being used. Without this, only country level location information will be available.

Comment: In my opinion it is not the children that they do not want knowing were they are but for other people seeing were they are.  As an app developer, I know there is no way to know what the companies are doing with your location data. Google has been slammed for privacy so much recently and this is a good step for them. It would be a shame if someone used a mobile phone app to harm a child by stalking and locating them.

Answer (score 0):

You can contact the support team at Google if you feel your app has been rated improperly. Per the [article mentioned above](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188189):

> Mis-rated Apps
>
> Please note that users can notify us if they believe an app is
>   incorrectly rated. If we agree that the flagged app is incorrectly
>   rated, we will re-rate it per our guidelines. Repeat offenders may be
>   subject to further action, up to and including account termination.

Just go to the following link to send an email to their team:

http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/request.py?contact_type=publishing